# Comparing two django variable in a django if block

Tags: python, django

I am having a tough time with following code.

```
{% if object.author == user.username %}
```

That code is not working neither giving error.

So I have articles app inside my django project. I want to make sure that if a user goes to their own post, then only they should be able to see delete and edit links (I will be placing them inside if block).

The Article model is as follows:

```
class Article(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
body = models.TextField()
date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
author = models.ForeignKey(
    settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('article_detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

Here

```
{{user.username}}

{{object.author}}
```

both are valid django variables.

```
{{user.username}}
```

specifies username of current logged in user

```
{{object.author}}
```

specifies author of that particular post.

Please help me out to implement with comparison logic of both variables. I am using python 3.6, django 2.1 and django template language.

Comment: You should post your models. Specifically the model of the `object` var in your template and any other relevant models, such as the `User` model

Comment: When you print them and check type, are they identical?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question would be easier to answer if you posted your models (and formatted your text correctly).

I presume that `object.author` is actually a ForeignKey to the User model. Therefore, you should compare directly with the user, not with the username attribute of the user:

```
{% if object.author == user %}
```